# Android wear app, No eligible devices for app install

Tags: android, wear-os

I developed a wearable app, worked fine on my devices (Nexus 5, Samsung Gear Live and Moto 360) and put on playstore. However, when I browse the app on PlayStore, it said "No eligible devices for app install".

These are the permissions:

Phone:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
```

Wear:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

I already tried this:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
    android:required="true" />
```

For both apps, still no luck. How to solve this problem? Thanks.

**Edit:** if you want to try the app, here is the link
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sleepalert.heartrate

**Edit 2**: 
For wear, I used this pair

```
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 21
```

For mobile, I used this (those are defaults when I generated my project)

```
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
```

**Edit 3:** after I remove the GET_TASKS permission as suggested, the app can be installed on my device running LolliPop 5, but not on my friend LolliPop 5.1, which is annoying since the newer one is supposed to be backwards compatible. Then if I change targetSdk to 22, it works on both. So in all, it's fine now. Hope helpful to somebody facing this crazy mess.

Comment: link to the play store so i can test if it downloads on my phone?   also make sure that you didn't put any country limitation while uploading, happens a lot ( quick google search of your problem).

Comment: @CptEric I've updated my post, sorry for the lengthy steps, but that's Google doctrine :(

Comment: well, first, congratulations on the concept. it seems that my phone is also not compatible.   i would suggest you try to check if the app is avaliable in every country or has any restriction (being still in beta we should have acces to it ,thought), and check if all the permissions are necessary , could be that one of them , like GET_TASKS, wich is deprecated  ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html )  could be blocking.   also, what api target are you pointing to when compiling / packaging the app?

Comment: @CptEric thanks, I've updated my post about about targetSdk

Comment: Seems correct...  In one of my apps this happened once, it was a problem of an unnecessary permission that made it not work. Try with that.

Comment: @CptEric updated, kudos to your permission thing

Comment: works! i'll post it as answer so you can pick it as the correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75299/discussion-between-tung-mai-le-and-cpteric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that my phone is also not compatible. i would suggest you try to check if the app is avaliable in every country or has any restriction (being still in beta we should have acces to it ,thought), and check if all the permissions are necessary , could be that one of them , like GET_TASKS, wich is deprecated ( developer.android.com/reference/android/… ) could be blocking.

Comment: Awesome answer, solves my headache for all night ^^.

Comment: usually android is a "little b***" about permissions.    once one app  had two versions, one for  tablet and one for phone ( different  options) , but the phone app only showed on the tablet market ( you could only see it from a tablet, but you were not elegible to download it).